# What statically compiled tools may i use to create HTML5 games?

Tags: html

Recently i heard about [gamemaker being able to export in html5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Maker#HTML5_version). I never used game maker and prefer having the ability to write code but i hate writing javascript. What tools with a statically compiled language may i use to create HTML5 games?

Comment: What type of games are you interested in?

Comment: @JamesBlack any that i feel like making but specifically i'd do simple 2d games that could be made with SDL with C.

Comment: There'll be no static compilation, because the tools have to compile to HTML5 + JavaScript.

Comment: @robertc: Both Dart and Java (using GWT) has static typing and compiles to JavaScript (and HTML5).

Comment: @Jonas If only static typing was what he'd asked for that would be perfect.

Comment: @robertc: ah ha. Static typing is what i meant.

Comment: @acidzombie24 You should edit your question to make that clear

Answer (score 3):

Tom here from Scirra, we are a 2 man team making an [HTML5 game engine called Construct 2](http://www.scirra.com).  It might be of interest to you as it exports games to HTML5/Javascript and an option for WebGL.  It's a popular alternative with people who don't like Game Maker.

You can see how fast results can be obtained and how powerful Construct 2 is with this 2 minute video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RlSmkSbleI

Also Construct 2 allows plugins to be written in Javascript to extend the functionality of Construct 2.  I know you say you hate writing Javascript, but it's good to have that option there for the future incase you change your mind or if you want to tweak something yourself.

Comment: what are the advantages of Construct2 over GameMaker?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/webtoolkit/) to write your game in Java and then compile to HTML5 and JavaScript.

There is also the upcoming [Dart programming language](http://www.dartlang.org/) that has static typing and compiles to JavaScript unless the browser has native support for Dart.

Not statically typed, but **[CoffeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/)** may be the best JavaScript alternative for HTML5 games at the moment. It's a nice languages that compiles to readable JavaScript.

Comment: agh, if only i knew java or even liked it. Dart isnt ready to be used in production yet

Comment: @acidzombie24; I have updated my answer. You should have a look on CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are looking for then is NaCl (http://code.google.com/chrome/nativeclient/), and for more intro info to it you can look at this:

http://code.google.com/games/technology-nacl.html

Basically, you can write your game in C, it gets compiled in the browser and runs as native code.

Comment: nacl doesnt output to html5 but its almost the same idea. +1 but unfortunately the last time i looked (less then3months ago) all the demos disappeared or didnt work. It doesnt appear to be ready for use yet

Comment: @acidzombie24 - If you go to http://www.gonacl.com/dev/sdk.html and click on a demo, and add it to Chrome, it worked for me, but I am also using Chrome.  I tested with Conway's Life